# How to play two videos at the same time with gstreamer？

Tags: video, gstreamer, xlib, playbin2

I want to play two videos at the same time with gstreamer.But I have no idea with it.I use playbin2 as the pipeline,xvimagesink as the sink element.Now I want this pipeline to play two videos.Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=160,height=120 ! m.sink_0 \
               videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=160,height=120 ! m.sink_1 \
                 videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=160 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=120 ! xvimagesink

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with playbin2, either use multiple playbin2 or create your own pipeline with multiple uridecodebin and link that to multiple sinks.

Also, gstreamer 0.10 is obsolete. Please move to the latest 1.0 version (currently 1.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

For playing two videos you can use videomixer and videobox components.  Advantage of these components is , both of the two videos will be played in a single window.

Or

You can use two sinks for those two videos, then those will be played in two different windows.